# How can I handle updating the database in my application and at the same time retaining user scores and settings?

Tags: android, xcode, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a phone application that uses a database of words and tests a user to see which words they know. I have a SQLite database with the words that I populate using a console application and this is then deployed as a resource to phones etc.

When the user runs the application then it stores pass fail data in the same database but in different tables.

When I update the application a fresh copy of the words database is installed on the phone and all the user data is lost.

How is this typically handled? Do phone applications that use SQLite have multiple databases with one being used to store user data and the other holding data which can be brought in when the application is first installed or updated?

If multiple databases are used then is it possible to create a look up from one database to the other?

Thanks in advance for any help, advice or links that point me in the right direction.

Comment: Usually you'd make database migrations when updating the schema.

Comment: @Egor - Can you explain a little bit more about what you mean?  The biggest problem I have is that I might be getting an updated table with a few hundred more entries that need to be added to the client.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question right. I think you can do well with a single database, but implementing your use case with 2 databases shouldn't be a problem also - you'll just have two `SQLiteOpenHelper` classes, which can query data from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a file (JSON, or plain text) to ship the words with the app. Then, when the app runs, it reads that file and adds the new words to the database. This won't affect the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to deal with that, we hard code the values into a static method in code. Then at runtime, we see if there is any data in the table and, if not, we grab the hard coded data and do an insert.

In your case, I would also just add a version number of some kind so then, if the version was lower or the table was empty, you do a delete all and then insert your new static data.